# Zend Framework - how to apply my own js plugin?

Tags: zend-framework, zendx

How can i add my own jQuery plug-in located in my zf path "public/js/isround.js"?
- to apply using Zend framework instead of manually putting this:

```
<script> $("#world").isRound('myPlugin'); </script>
```

1. jQuery setup is working

   ```
   $this->jQuery()->setLocalPath('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js')
                  ->enable()
                  ->setUiLocalPath('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js')
                  ->uiEnable()
                  ->addStylesheet('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css');
   ```
2. file application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml, i have:

   < div id="world"> _____my js plugin apply here _____< /div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a view helper.
[zend documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.view.html)
Check out:
Example #2 Building your own Helper with No Conflict Mode

Also a tutorial about viewhelpers and jquery [Zendcast](http://www.zendcasts.com/zend-view-helpers-with-ajax/2009/03/)

Here is some code:
Create a folder in your library folder called Mylib.
In it create a folder views.
In views create a folder helpers.
In helpers create a file named: IsRound.php

```
<?php

class Mylib_Views_Helpers_IsRound {
    public function isRound($elem){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("'.$elem.'").isRound();</script>';
    }
}
```

In the indexAction in IndexController.php

```
$this->view->addHelperPath('Mylib/views/helpers', 'Mylib_Views_Helpers');
```

In index.phtml:

```
<?php $this->isRound('#elem'); ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: there examples are never easy for me, can you show me a example in my case code are like this: http://gist.github.com/480330

Comment: Try watching those tutorials on zendcast they are of immense help and are pretty easy to follow. Ill try to make an exemple later.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for?

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/isround.js');
```

Comment: Yes, it added the script, but how can i call using ZF. $('#world').isRound('test');